# React js error WARNING in [eslint] src\App.js Line 2:8: 'person' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, frontend, jsx

[![I am facing this issue help me to solve this. it always gives me an error Line 2:8:  'person' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars.][1]][1]

Comment: It's a eslint error. You have to remove unused variable according to the rule of eslint. https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/scope-manager-interface#deprecated-members

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the editor settings and search `eslint` and disable the checkbox of `Controls whether eslint is enableed or not.` But that's not appritiated cause eslint gives you international code standard in some cases by applying eslint rule. If you want to know more please read [eslint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 at the position 8, in the file App.js you declared a variable with the name "person" that you are not using in your code.
Its a hint not an error,, by eslint.
Go to this position and delete the declaration.